# Busy Beaver Instruction Generator and Computablity

Tags: computability, turing-machines, busy-beaver

**Question 1**

From busy beaver uncomputablity it follows that we cannot design algorithm that for every input N, generate the appropriate set of TM instructions (the bit value of every bit in every card) that run and output BB(N). 
As i understand, the number of bits in the cards is growing almost linearly with N, so the uncomputablity situation is very strange. What prevent us in principle to design such algorithm from theoretical point of view?

**Question 2**

If we allow the instruction set itself to be part of memory, so that the bussy beaver will be able to change the instruction set while running, will we get faster growing function?

**Question 3**

If busy beaver is solution to optimization problem, is there anyway to know if some physical process that we are witnessed to, is a solution to same kind of optimization problem?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per post. Also, I don't really understand Question 1. The answer to Question 2 is that if you change the model of computation, you'll get a different function. The answer to Question 3 is: No.

Comment: I did mistake in question 1: Output is BB(N), fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of bits in the cards is growing almost linearly with N"?

Comment: If i got it right than every card include 4bits+2log(N) bits. So N cards goes like NlogN. And i meant to say that this is not close to be fast growing as BB(N). So maybe this instruction set is commutable. But it will lead to contradiction.

Comment: And about question 2, if the computation model is dynamic  than it is reasonable to assume that you can get faster growing function.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "the number of bits in the cards is growing almost linearly with N". To start off, I don't know what you mean by "cards". I only know the definition of the busy beaver function in terms of Turing machines: $BB(N)$ is the largest number of steps that a halting Turing machine having $N$ states takes before halting.

Comment: Card is just the hardware that hold the state. (punch-card)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61113/discussion-between-mendi-barel-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: In fact, while the *description* of the Turing machine takes roughly $N$ bits, the value of the busy beaver function itself is much much larger.

Comment: My question is exactly about this fact. Why we cant in principal find expression for the description? it behave like normal function.